# Mysterious Android(Java) error on ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

There is a mysterious error at the line `ee.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid","demo"));`

Eclipse says:

> Multiple markers at this line
>   - Syntax error on token "add", = expected after this token
>   - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

```
package com.test;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.http.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HttpMysqlActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> ee = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    ee.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid","demo"));//error occurs here
}
```

I don't know what the problem is, because `ArrayList` do have the method `add()`, and I saw many people (e.g. [Link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database) a tutorial of Connecting to MySQL database) code like this. That's why it is mysterious.

Can anybody tell me why did Eclipse throw the error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're trying to call a method in the main class body. All you can have there is declarations. Put the `ee.add()` call inside the `onCreate` (or another method) and it will work.